# Do application installers set folder permissions? Or is it up to Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, permissions, uac, windows-installer

*Before anyone asks, yes I'm still running Photoshop CS2, it does the job ;-)*

I installed Photoshop CS2 as Administrator. I then copied some plug-ins into Photoshop's plug-ins folder. I did *not* get the expected UAC elevation prompt; the plug-ins just copied over. Weird. So I looked at the folder permissions and found something very odd.

The `Adobe` folder has permissions I'm used to seeing (they're just inherited from parent). But all the sub-folders got sweeping permissions *that allow all users full control*. What caused this? Is it by design of the Photoshop installer, or did Windows do some kind of silent "compatibility" tweak because it knows CS2 is old and somewhat non-compliant?

**Permissions on the `Adobe` folder:**
[image]

**Permissions on the sub-folders**
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: What Windows is this?  You tagged this for Windows 7 and Windows 8.1

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry I forgot to mention in the question, *both*. I have tested installing Photoshop in Windows 7 and 8.1 with the same result. I am about to test in a Windows XP virtual machine, when I get a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was probably the Photoshop installer. Windows does do a few things to help older apps run, but I've never heard of this.

Comment: You are spot on. Adobe released a security patch for CS2, to correct this issue (which was indeed their fault): https://www.adobe.com/support/techdocs/332644.html